# Combine Grafana metrics with mismatched labels

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I have two metrics (relating to memory usage in my Kubernetes pods) defined as follows:

1. kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes{app="kube-state-metrics",**container="foo"**,instance="10.244.0.7:8080",job="kubernetes-endpoints",kubernetes_name="kube-state-metrics",kubernetes_namespace="monitoring",namespace="test",node="aks-nodepool1-25518080-0",**pod="foo-cb9bc5fb5-2bghz"**}
2. container_memory_working_set_bytes{agentpool="nodepool1",beta_kubernetes_io_arch="amd64",beta_kubernetes_io_instance_type="Standard_A2",beta_kubernetes_io_os="linux",**container_name="foo"**,failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_region="westeurope",failure_domain_beta_kubernetes_io_zone="1",id="/kubepods/burstable/pod5b0099a9-eeff-11e8-884b-ca2011a99774/eeb183b21e2b3226a32de41dd85d7a2e9fc8715cf31ea7109bfbb2cae7c00c44",image="@sha256:6d6003ba86a0b7f74f512b08768093b4c098e825bd7850db66d11f66bc384870",instance="aks-nodepool1-25518080-0",job="kubernetes-cadvisor",kubernetes_azure_com_cluster="MC_test.planned.bthbygg.se_bthbygg-test_westeurope",kubernetes_io_hostname="aks-nodepool1-25518080-0",kubernetes_io_role="agent",name="k8s_foo_foo-cb9bc5fb5-2bghz_test_5b0099a9-eeff-11e8-884b-ca2011a99774_0",namespace="test",**pod_name="foo-cb9bc5fb5-2bghz"**,storageprofile="managed",storagetier="Standard_LRS"}

I want to combine these two into a percentage, by doing something like

```
container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace="test"}
  / kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes{namespace="test"}
```

but that gives me no data back, presumably because there are no matching labels to join the data sets on. As you can see, I do have matching label *values*, but the label *names*  don't match.

Is there somehow I can formulate my query to join these on e.g. `pod == pod_name`, without having to change the metrics at the other end (where they are exported)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PromQL [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace()) function to create a new matching label from the original labels.

For instance, you can use the below expression to add a `container_name="foo"` label to the first metric which can be used to do the join:

```
label_replace(
 kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes,
 "container_name", "$1", "container", "(.*)")
```

You can use the above patern to create new labels that can be used for the matching.